# Whats wrong with changing the tableview height with bottom constraint

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I have a parent view which has a tableview and tableviews leading,trailing,top,bottom is zero.

and I have a label to show if there are no records ... to show a message and I have vertically and horizontally centered it.

Based on content size of tableview I have to change the parentview's height and i can't directly do because there is no height property defined for parent view .. only leading,trailing,top and bottom property.

Now I have to change the bottom property value with respect to tables content size

if there are no records have to set the bottom constraint to higher value so that parent view height reduces

(Xamarin c# but constraints are same as iOS objective c or swift no change though)

```
      if(vuParent.Frame.Height - tblMine.ContentSize.Height > 0 && !tblMine.Hidden && tblMine.ContentSize.Height!=0)

     {

   constraintBottomvuParent.Constant = 10 + vuParent.Frame.Height - tblMine.ContentSize.Height;

      }
            else if(vuParent.Frame.Height - tblMine.ContentSize.Height < 0)    
  {

         constraintBottomvuParent.Constant = 10;

      }else
      {
    constraintBottomvuParent.Constant = 200;
     }
```

if there is any better way kindly let me know

Thanks

Comment: Actually i don't know why you need `change the parentview's height`

Comment: if there are less records then I don't want empty tableview rows to appear

Comment: If you don't want empty tableview rows to appear, you just need to assign an empty view for your tableView footer

Comment: oh .. is it ? Just assigning a empty view will fix the problem ... the height of empty view should be equal to number of empty rows

Comment: you just need to assign an empty view which has frame (0,0,0,0). Don't need to calculate its height. Please let me know if you can fix it ;)

Comment: @trungduc - Thanks let me trt

Comment: @Thanks it works .. but i would really appreciate if I could change the tabel height as it'll look good... if you don't mind, can you help me

Comment: Tell me what is your `vuParent` view?

Comment: its just a view that contains this table and one label which is vertically and horizontally center of this view.. the label will say no records...basically I will round the corners of parent view to give elegant appearance...

Comment: Basically table rounded corner is getting affected at bottom if i give null view for foooter... so I have to round parent view instead of tableview

Comment: Long story short ... I want to show a tableview that autogrows and autoreduces depending on its content... and the corners should be rounded... in our case autogrow,auto reduction is not problem but rounded corner is problem

Comment: Ok, i understand. Let create a property for table height and change constant of it when you want

Comment: But this requires lots of hardcoding ....thats one more problem .. if we could fix the rounded corner problem it'd be great

Comment: Actually you will calculate height of `tableView` so it isn't hard code. As i understand, if you want to fix the rounded corner problem, you need to make tableView have right height

Comment: Yeah there lies the problem . then we'll have to individually calculate maximum height it can grow for individual sizes ... for example .. iPHone 4 might accomodate just 3 rows... 5s 4 rows.. etc.. so for each individual devices we'll have to decide maximum height it can grow and thats hardcodeing rigth ....!

Comment: No. We have cell's height, we have screen height. So it's easy to do it.

Comment: @trungduc - Ok ..Lets do it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158354/discussion-between-trungduc-and-shiva).